# WHY: Mini Displayport to Displayport adapter connected to Alienware m17 laptop for dual monitor not working?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, displayport, mini-displayport, display-adapter

I just bought this: 
**accellcables.com/K088B-003B.html** 
and am trying to connect my ASUS 27" (2560x1440) monitor up to my laptop through it's mini displayport. After wrestling through possible solutions I finally got the other monitor to come on (for 2 seconds) after simply unplugging and plugging the displayport back into the adapter and then it flickered back to black and could not find the monitor. I have no idea why it's doing this...

The steps I took:

- I thought that maybe it had to with the intel chip still being enabled so i went into nvidia control panel and switched to always being the geforce 680m card. no luck there..
- I rebooted and no luck there...
- I right click on my desktop i'd expect to see the nvidia control panel pop up- Nope... still the intel chip options/control panel.
- I updated both Intel HD 4000 chipset and NVIDIA GeForce 680m chipset to latest drivers, no luck there.

My first guess is that it has something to do with the Nvidia Geforce card not being the default card and I dont know how to force it to be.. but I'm pretty lost on how to handle it at this point.